# Manhwa that use chess pieces as his power

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I remember vividly that the manwha starts when the MC return to Earth naked, and meets with his childhood friend, and realises that the world he left before isn't the same anymore. The MC uses chess pieces as his power to summon his minion.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.   Where and when did you read this?

Comment: Was the minion chess-themed?

Comment: I read the manhwa few months ago and can't remember i read it where but i remember that the queen piece has its own ego that mc seems have trouble to control